# Value of the sum, $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{\sin(n)}{n}\right)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I was trying to determine whether or not the following sum, $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{\sin(n)}{n}\right)$$, would converge or diverge. I thought that this function would diverge, as it is comparable to the harmonic series, which is $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{n}}$$, but I remembered that the ranges from 0 to 1. So, it can be viewed as having $(-1)^n$, which means this sum would converge as $$\lim_{n\to\infty}{\frac{\sin(n)}{n}} = 0$$

So, what value would the sum converge to?

Comment: It is comparable and it can be viewed is pretty loose language for math :) The answer is $1/2 \cdot (\pi-1)$

Comment: @rtybase yeah. Apparently, I did not look hard enough to find the solution to my question. Thanks!

Comment: The partial sums $\sum_{n=1}^p \sin(n)$ is bounded and $\frac1n$ monotonic decreases to $0$. You can apply [Dirichlet's test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet's_test) to conclude the series conditonally converges. When a series $\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k$ conditionally converges, you can apply [Abel's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel's_theorem) to evaluate it $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k = \lim_{t\to 1^-} \sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k t^k$$ For this series,  $\sin(n) = \Im e^{in}$ and  $-\log(1-z) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{z^n}{n}$ for $|z| < 1$, ...